# Authentification failed only in non-interactive mode

Tags: bash, lftp

When using this syntax:

```
lftp my_user@domain.net@domain.net #yes my login is my_user@domain.net !
```

i can then type my password, connect the ftp server and download any files i want. But then i am in interactive mode.

As i want to use a bash script  for files download automation, i tried this syntax :

```
lftp -c "open -u my_user@domain.net@domain.net,my_password domain.net; pget e_20210214_daily.csv /home/user/local_folder/"
```

I always get this error message :

pget: e_20210214_daily.csv: L'authentification a échoué.: 530 Login authentication failed
« /home/user/local_folder/ » at 0

Do not know what I am missing there.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 2021-02-20

I read some more on `lftp`, and you could try:

**1**: Use `lftp -f script_file`

`script_file` should contain:

```
open -u my_user@domain.net,my_password domain.net
pget e_20210214_daily.csv /home/user/local_folder/
```

**2**: Or use `lftp -e CMD -u my_user@domain.net,my_password domain.net`

Where CMD would be: `"pget e_20210214_daily.csv /home/user/local_folder/"`

Comment: Thanks for response. The username/login i was given is "my_user@domain.net", so i tried again with :
lftp -c "open -u my_user@domain.net,my_password domain.net; pget e_20210214_daily.csv /home/user/local_folder/" 
but i got an 530 Login autentification failed.
The authentification works when using Filezilla.